# Forcing hipcc to use GPU architecture specific custom header libraries

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, dependencies, amd-rocm

I have been trying to compile a ROCm GPU program example using custom versions of rocPRIM and Thrust supporting my GPU architecture which are located at:

- `/opt/rocm-5.4.0/myspecialrocm/include/thrust/`
- `/opt/rocm-5.4.0/myspecialrocm/include/rocprim/`

The compiler instructions I am using are:

```
hipcc --offload-arch=gfx1031 -I=/opt/rocm-5.4.0/myspecialrocm/include/thrust -I=/opt/rocm-5.4.0/myspecialrocm/include/rocprim discrete_voronoi.cu -o testvoronoi
```

Unfortunately the compiler uses the default installations of rocPRIM and Thrust located at:

- `/opt/rocm-5.4.0/include/rocprim`
- `/opt/rocm-5.4.0/include/thrust`

When I compiled rocThrust, I used the parameter `-DCMAKE_NO_SYSTEM_FROM_IMPORTED=TRUE` which should enable the use the custom libraries but the compiler keeps using the default versions.

How can I overwrite the default paths at compile time?

(The example was correctly compiled when I installed the custom versions of rocPRIM and Thrust including the examples and it works fine but I am not able to compile my own programs because I haven't found a way to enforce the use of my custom libraries.)